# Insert data statements in Laravel 5 - a neater way?

Tags: php, database, laravel-5

Following the convention in the docs [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database) this is my insert statement:

```
$input = Request::all();

DB::insert('
            insert into at (studentID, completedBy, timeStamp, contact, intervention, level, goal, access, recording, support, motivators, notes)
            values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
            [ $input['studentID'], $input['completedBy'], $input['timeStamp'], $input['contact'], $input['intervention'], $input['level'], $input['goal'], $input['access'], $input['recording'], $input['support'], $input['motivators'], $input['notes'] ]);
```

Whilst it works fine, it seems stupidly long and therefore hard to replicate for additional tables with different values; is there a neater / better way to construct the statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you leverage Models and Eloquent ORM you can use the create method.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#mass-assignment

As mentioned in the docs, if you have a Flight Model (this would correspond to a table in your database such as `flights`)

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Flight extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
}
```

You can then call the `create` method on the `$fillable` attributes for the model as so:

```
$flight = App\Flight::create(['name' => 'Flight 10']);
```

Hope that gets you started.

I believe your implementation would look something like this:

**Model**

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class At extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'at'; // put your table name here

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'studentID',
        'completedBy',
        'timeStamp',
        'contact',
        'intervention',
        'level',
        'goal',
        'access',
        'recording',
        'support',
        'motivators',
        'notes',
    ];
}
```

**Insert**

```
App\At::create([
    'studentID'    => $input['studentID'],
    'completedBy'  => $input['completedBy'],
    'timeStamp'    => $input['timeStamp'],
    'contact'      => $input['contact'],
    'intervention' => $input['intervention'],
    'level'        => $input['level'],
    'goal'         => $input['goal'],
    'access'       => $input['access'],
    'recording'    => $input['recording'],
    'support'      => $input['support'],
    'motivators'   => $input['motivators'],
    'notes'        => $input['notes'],
]);
```

I believe if your statement `$input = Request::all();` only includes the values that are expected for the model create method you may just be able to do this:

```
$input = Request::all();

App\At::create($input);
```

without the `['key' => 'value']`